# Heapsort in C, index 0 issue

Tags: c, vector, heapsort

for a project for school I have decided to solve a problem by coding a HeapSort but I have an issue. ("vector" is the vector to sort and "n" is the number of elements in "vector")

Here is my code :

```
void fixHeap(int position,int length)
{
    int next=2*position;
    int temp;

    while (next<=length)
    {
        if (next<length && vector[next]<vector[next+1])
        {
            next++;
        }
        if (vector[position]<vector[next])
        {
            temp=vector[position];
            vector[position]=vector[next];
            vector[next]=temp;
            position=next;
            next=2*position;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void heapSort()
{
    int counter;
    int temp;

    for(counter=(n-1)/2;counter!=0;counter--)
    {
        fixHeap(counter,n-1);
    }
    for(counter=n-1;counter>0;counter--)
    {
        temp=vector[counter]; 
        vector[counter]=vector[0];
        vector[0]=temp;
        fixHeap(0,counter-1);
    }
    display();
}
```

When I'm doing fixHeap(0,n-1) I'm putting next to 0 and then position is also at 0 so I'm not really doing the Heap right. Could someone help me fixing it?

Also are there other mistakes that you spotted that I may have overlooked?

Comment: `for(counter=(n-1)/2;counter==0;counter--)` makes no sense. It's pretty much equal to `if((n-1)/2 == 0)`

Comment: Why? I'm doing counter-- so I'll eventually go to counter==0.

Comment: Do you want `counter != 0`, then? Your code is equivalent to `counter = (n - 1) / 2; while(counter == 0) { /* ... */ counter--; }` which will execute once if counter is 0 or not at all otherwise.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right I'm stupid. But that doesn't change the other problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children of the i-th node are are at 2*i and 2*i+1.   But if you want to sort every item in the array, the 1st node is at index 0.  You need to fix your child node index calculations accordingly.

Comment: would next=(2*position)+1 fix the whole problem? Do you see any other mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: 2 * (pos+1).   And after a swap, shouldn't you check the other child?

Comment: (2*pos)+1 check the first child and in my code next can increase by one if vector[next]<vector[next+1]. So I guess it's fine.

Comment: OK, You are right about the indexing.  But why does the initial loop in `heapSort()` have `counter!=0`?   The element at vector[0] is never considered in building the heap.